# Error with software updater: "E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/clipgrab-team/ppa/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file."

Tags: boot, apt, updates

```
E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/clipgrab-team/ppa/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to askubuntu.com! That error shows up because repository doesn't provide packages for Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish). The most recent release for which it provides packages is 18.04 Bionic Beaver.